# Is there a phrase for someone being ashamed of, or self-conscious about their accent when moving to another region?

Tags: phrases, terminology, linguistics, accent

I was reading a book about accents at a local library and there was a chapter where the author says "some varieties of a language are more aesthetically pleasing than others". Some accents are considered “tops”, and these are the ones spoken by the Royals, the elite, intellectuals and distinguished academics, etc

Consequently, a person might regard their own accent with distaste and may try to imitate the accent of the elite where they live or the elite who live in great cultural centers; for example, a French-Canadian in Paris, a Brummie in London, or a Texan in Boston.

As for the answer to my question, there is one, I know. It's a **phrase**, with 3 or 4 words, and no foreign terms. It is mentioned in the book on sociolinguistics and accents I was reading. I simply can't remember it now. I'm looking for a **phrase** describing the person or the condition.

For Clarity: I'm not saying that all French-Canadians, Brummies or Texans are, or should ever be, ashamed/embarrassed/self-conscious of their accents, but it is *possible*.

Comment: I'm not even aware of there being a word or phrase for someone being ashamed of any specific attribute relating to their place of origin. Come to that, off-hand I can't think of any words referring to being ashamed of *any specific attribute at all*, let alone a "location-based" one.

Comment: It's intimidating, or embarrassing, or makes you self-conscious. It's kind of like asking if there's a specific word or phrase for the embarrassment you feel when you walk out of the mens room into a crowded lobby, hear snickers nearby, look about you and find you're trailing toilet paper on your shoe. (As a Quebecois in Paris, I did feel this way. It was silly. They use as many short-cuts and slang as most Quebecois. There I was, *Je vous-ing* while they were *Shte-ing". Pffft.) Oh, and I guaran-damn-TEE you that no Texan wants to talk like a Bostoner.

Comment: @medica This question hasn’t come to my mind out of the blue.  I was reading  a book about accents at a local library and there was a chapter where the author says "some varieties of a language are more aesthetically pleasing than others".  Some accents are considered “tops”, and these are the ones spoken by the Royals, the elite, intellectuals and distinguished academics, etc.  I’m not inventing this, it’s a fact. A person who grew up in rural Texas,  went to College in New England and graduated from Harvard Medical School  might (I said might) be ashamed of what was left of native accent.

Comment: @medica .  I agree that most Texans wouldn’t care whether their accents are pleasing or not, but some people do feel ashamed of their accents:  in the U.S., in Britain, in Spain, in Italy, you name it.  That’s why I’ve posted the question.  What I don’t understand is “It's intimidating, or embarrassing, or makes you self-conscious”  in your comment.  Does it refer to my question?  Why?

Comment: "A person who grew up in rural Texas, went to College in New England and graduated from Harvard Medical School might (I said might) be ashamed of what was left of native accent." I have a very hard time believing that. There are classes in every society, but Americans have never had royalty, and most of us don't look down on people because they have southern or northern accents. I think you might want to use examples from your personal experience rather than imagine odd things about the US. "Does it refer to my question?" Didn't you ask about being ashamed? How does one miss the connection?

Comment: If your phenomenon is as common as you say, then there must be a word for it in Spanish or Italian (you speak Spanish, what is the word in Spanish? If there's not a word for it, why isn't there? And, is there a single Spanish word for the guy who's trailing toilet paper on his shoe? We don't have one for that, either.

Comment: @medica  I have no idea where you are from, but I lived in central Massachusetts for five years and I can tell you some people are not exactly prejudiced against the Southern accent. They simply don't find it pleasant. Don't generalize, please, I said "some" people.  In the same way, some insecure southerner living in New England may feel he should try to acquire the NE accent.

Comment: As for the answer to my question, there is one, I know.  It is mentioned in  the book on linguistics and accents I was reading. I simply can't remember it now.  But please don't compare it to the toilet-paper-on-the-shoe question, because this one is serious, the term was coined by a linguist, and I may later offer several references.

Comment: I am from New England. And I said, "and most of us don't look down on people because they have southern or northern accents." That is not a generalization. It's life experience. I happen to like Southern drawls. In my whole life, I'm not sure I ever heard a real complaint about them (some funnin', yes.) I would not say the same thing of an Appalachian accent. But that's discrimination on our part, not shame on theirs. Good for you that you have an answer. Why ask the question, then?

Comment: @medica it is possible that an aspiring actor might feel a Texan drawl / strong Glawegian accent (one of the most difficult accents to decipher!) / any marked regional accent is a handicap to his/her art. Imagine hearing Macbeth with an Alabama or Jamaican accent, and now imagine if you were a theatre director who had to cast an actor for the role.

Comment: However, to be actually *ashamed* of one's accent is a sentiment that I believe is no longer true nowadays. Call the accent thing a handicap, or a hinder to one's ambition, but you would be hard pushed to find anyone who is so ashamed of their origin they hide the truth by adopting a neutral or, if you like, an RP accent.

Comment: @medica I'm not sure what you are saying. Are you saying that if a real world activity is common enough, there must be a single word for it? What is the word then for going to a grocery store to buy food? The term for it is grocery shopping, but that's two words.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Are you saying that being ashamed of/being prejudiced about an accent is not the case nowadays? Maybe in your view but in my experience, even in the US, but I expect in the UK, Aus/NZ frankly all languages, there is social status (hi/lo) associated with every accent. and people judge others/themselves because of it. It's like you're saying racism doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: @Mitch   You can be prejudiced against somebody's accent, but I have never heard of anyone say they were actually *ashamed* of their own accent. I believe a distinctive accent  can be a hindrance, or a drawback to one's career (some people even play down their "posh" upbringing); and one can be self-conscious or even embarrassed by it, but not ashamed. Just because prejudice exists, it doesn't imply the person being discriminated feels ashamed of who they are. Being ashamed of one's origin was probably truer in the 19th and 20th century.

Comment: @Mari-LouA   re. " but I have never heard of anyone say they were actually ashamed of their own accent."  When someone is ashamed of one of their characteristics, chances are they will never mention it in public.  I've never heard anyone say "My father was once in prison for 5 years and I'm ashamed of it", "My mother had an affair with a friend of mine and my father never heard about it.", "I'm illiterate, did you know that ?"

Comment: @Mitch - I don't think it's a complete fallacy to say that the more common the subject, the more likely it will be expressed in one word or a short phrase. Plagiarism. Overdiagnosis. Debt. Birding. Nostalgia. Karyotyping. Etc. My point was to emphasize that this is not the normative experience the OP claims it is. I'm not terribly fond of SWR to being with. When a high rep user posts a SWR because he saw an obscure word in a linguistics book and just wants to flaunt it, I like it less, and irrationality is expressed. I should know better. My apologies, and thanks for the reminder.

Comment: @Mari-LouA [one example of many](http://accentadventure.com/ashamed-of-accents/) google for 'ashamed accent'

Comment: @Mitch non-native speakers who are  ashamed of speaking English in an American accent. *Really...?* The ones I know would be thrilled if they could pull off an American or standard British accent. I speak fluent Italian but with a British accent, and even after all this time some Italians still take the mickey. I've heard people parroting Oliver & Hardy, ([Stanlio & Olio](https://youtu.be/0Lqn4zWP4PE?t=1m9s) in Italian), Shel Shapiro and [Mal](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=57Rg_6253CE) at me for years. If anything I just laughed about it.

Comment: @Centaurus there's a huge difference between telling a stranger your father was in prison, or your mother had an illicit affair and speaking to them in your native accent! An accent is damn hard to hide, as soon as you open your mouth you reveal your economic and social status (if you're British). Much, much less so in Italy, I don't know how true this is in the rest of Europe, although  I've heard of Parisians who are snobby about accents.

Comment: @Mari-LouA  I guess I used wrong examples.  Let me try to fix it: a young man who has a dispoprotionate nose and is ashamed of it won't go around telling people how he feels about it.  The same with a girl who has very small breasts.  People don't go around saying "I'm ashamed of this characteristic of mine".  Whatever we don't like in ourselves, we tend not to mention.

Comment: Probably : dominant native accent concious

Comment: @Mari-LouA  Thank you for editing the question into a more literary format. I wouldn't have removed the last paragraph, but it's ok that you have.  You must know better.  :-)

Comment: [An/the Eliza Doolittle Complex](http://www.the-exponent.com/the-eliza-doolittle-complex/) probably covers the whole package and not just ones accent, but it does include the accent.

Comment: @Mari-LouA  The phrase I'm looking for is about a person feeling bad (ashamed, embarrassed, self-conscious, uncomfortable) about his accent.  Generally, such a person moved from his native region and everyone here has a different accent which is considered proper (by some) ,  whereas his is considered of an inferior quality (by some).  How would you phrase a question like that?

Comment: Weren't you looking for a phrase coined by a linguist? Something you once read in a sociolinguistic  book, an expression that is technical, specific, that conveys the low prestige/opinion that some may have against a dialect. None of the answers posted so far have come close, have they? It's a rare term, not a common everyday one. At one point, you're asking for a single word, so you must remember something; long, short, foreign sounding, difficult to pronounce; I dunno! An "outcast" fits, but that's too easy!

Comment: @Mari-LouA You missed my point.  First you said "I suggest writing a less ambiguous title, one that..." and then I asked you how you would phrase the title and still convey what I mean.  As for the answer, I remember it wasn't a single word.  it was a phrase,  perhaps 3 or 4 words with "linguistic or linguistically" included, no foreing word in it.  I'm going to re-edit, delete "word" and leave only "phrase".

Comment: Do you remember the name of the book in which the phrase occurred?

Comment: @ab2 Sorry but I can't.  It would make things much easier.

Comment: You are setting a puzzle to which you know the answer?  Fair enough.

Comment: @ab2  You misunderstood me.  Read again "sorry but I can't" is the answer to "Do you remember".   It would make things much easier and perhaps I would find the answer myself.

Comment: Sorry, I jumped to a conclusion.

Comment: I'm unsure of the SOP here, so I'll refrain from downvoting on the grounds of "not useful". I don't like requests for "that [thing] I forgot, and only that thing I forgot", that belongs on Puzzling.SE. "Starts with an 'E' and means..." is fine by me, but "begins and ends with some obscure phrase someone wrote in a book", not so much.

Comment: @Mazura   Excuse my ignorance but SOP stands for........?

Comment: Standard Operating Procedure (I was actually referring to my own, personal one).

Comment: @Mazura  Producer?  Don't you mean "procedure"?   I was writing this while you edited.  OK. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

He/she felt [**linguistically discriminated**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linguistic_discrimination) or to be precise [**accentually discriminated**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accent_(sociolinguistics)#Accent_discrimination).
The condition is called [**accentism**](http://www.bbc.co.uk/newsbeat/article/28225710/accentism-similar-to-racism-suggests-new-research).

> Linguistic discrimination is the unfair treatment of an individual based solely on their use of language. This use of language may include the individual's native language or other characteristics of the person's speech, such as an **accent**, the size of vocabulary, and syntax.

***Update:***

**[phonetic accommodation:](http://www.degruyter.com/view/j/labphon.2014.5.issue-1/lp-2014-0006/lp-2014-0006.xml)** Phonetic imitation is the unintentional, spontaneous acquisition of speech characteristics of the interlocutor.

> **Novelty and social preference in phonetic accommodation**
>   Previous work has shown that imitation is strongly moderated by social preference in adults, and that social preference affects children's speech acquisition within peer groups. [linguistics.berkley.edu](http://linguistics.berkeley.edu/dissertations/Babel_dissertation_2009.pdf)

(Also see. [Communication accommodation theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Communication_accommodation_theory))

Comment: http://www.utdallas.edu/research/FAS/ Jimmy

Comment: This one comes close to what I'm looking for.  "Accentism" refers to how other people react to a different or strange accent.  My question refers to what or how some people may feel about their own accent being different.

Comment: The quote in brown says "This isn't about hating their accent, it's about **being afraid of** how others will think about them."

Comment: The question has been re-edited and some more information added.

Answer (score 3):

Are you looking for [Communication accomodation theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Communication_accommodation_theory)?  Specifically:

***convergence*** -

> Convergence refers to the process through which an individual shifts his or her speech patterns in interaction so that they more closely resemble the speech patterns of speech partners. 
>   ...
>
> People use convergence based on their perceptions of others, as well as what they are able to infer about them and their backgrounds. 
>   ...
>
> Thus when an individual shifts his speech and non-verbal behaviors in order to assimilate to the other it can result in a more favorable appraisal of him, that is: when convergence is perceived positively it is likely to enhance both the conversation and the attraction between the listener and the speaker. For this reason it could be said that convergence reflects “an individual’s desire for social approval”[3] from his interlocutor, and that the greater the individual’s need for social approval, the more likely he or she is to converge.

In any event I didn't dig up an name for a converger in this sense, but I thought this might help the discussion.

Comment: Something like that, but a phrase specific for an individual felling embarrassed about his accent being completely different from the one spoken by everyone else, especially because his accent isn't exactly appreciated.  "We can all see that Sean has been trying to get rid of his Yorkshire accent.  This is a clear case of .........................."

Comment: Considering the question has but one succinct phrase of an answer, all of them are wrong, except this one is useful (Jimmy's and Glenn's too). Without these answers rising to the top, this is unlikely to be of help to future readers.

Comment: @Mazura  I've found the answer I was looking for.http://www.nytimes.com/1995/01/22/magazine/the-big-city-can-we-talk.html

Comment: @Centaurus "linguistic self-hatred"? I loled at "socially ambitious New Yorkers started copying Midwesterners when saying *fourth floor*." My P's say that I *do* have an accent, but I disagree: I sound just like the (news) people on TV. If I want to sound hip, I have to consciously pronounce 'dog' *dawg*. Also, I thought *dems guys and dowes people* WAS a Chicago accent.

Answer (score 2):

Self conscious:  Defined by Merriam Webster as: "uncomfortably nervous about or embarrassed by what other people think about you..."  I've used the phrase in a sentence to make the phrase clearer. "She rarely spoke up in meetings because she was self-conscious about her accent."

Comment: But that could be because of having three heads or smelling of aduki beans.

Comment: self-conscious isn't specific for accents.

Comment: Since OP is asking about someone "self-conscious about their accent", the answer "self-conscious" seems unhelpful.

Comment: @vladkornea  Point taken.  I read the post too quickly. Mea culpa.  But, just possibly, the OP came up with the best word.  Great minds, and all that. So I am going to leave my answer.

Comment: For the sake of clarity, the OP edited the title *after* ab2 posted their suggestion. See edit history [No 4](http://english.stackexchange.com/revisions/260157/4) and here [No 5](http://english.stackexchange.com/revisions/260157/5)

Comment: The question has been re-edited and some more information added.

Comment: @Mari-Lou  I don't have much experience with this site.  Does the site etiquette say I should delete my answer?  If so, I will if I am asked to do so, but I don't know if your comment and Centaurus's are FYIs or hints.

Comment: You answer was appropriate before the OP edits, and now less so. But that's not your fault, and you earned two upvotes (20 points) which you would lose if you were to delete this answer. You can either leave your answer as it is, knowing you won't be awarded the bounty, or edit your post by suggesting a new linguistic **phrase** and be in with a chance.

Answer (score 1):

Two possibilities spring to mind:

- **Diglossia**

  > A situation in which two languages (or two varieties of the same language) are used under different conditions within a community, often by the same speakers. The term is usually applied to languages with distinct ‘high’ and ‘low’ (colloquial) varieties [...]. [[Oxford](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/diglossia) & [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diglossia#Sociolinguistics) (for the socioluingistic link)]
- **Hypercorrection** (sometimes called **hyperurbanism**)

  > Use of hypercorrect forms in language. [[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hyperurbanism)]
  >
  > Hypercorrection is sometimes found among speakers of less prestigious language varieties who produce forms associated with high-prestige varieties, even in situations where speakers of those varieties would not. Some commentators call such production hyperurbanism. [[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypercorrection)]

There's also **echolalia**, but as you are talking about *conciously* altering your accent, I doubt that's the word you're looking for.

Comment: The question has been re-edited and some more information added.

Answer (score 1):

These may describe the condition, rather than the person who might feel anxiety that they're being judged; that their accent is seen as a "qualifier" of social status:

Sociolinguistic discrimination; 
Linguistic profiling;
Ethnocentrism;
Linguicism;
Classism;
Cultural bias;
Socioeconomic stereotyping; Dialectical stigmatism; Patois prejudice; class condescension, etc.

Perhaps some mix/match of these will help jog your memory for the phrase you're searching for.

Comment: Although it's not a phrase [**linguicism**](http://grammar.about.com/od/il/g/linguicismterm.htm) describes the discrimination aspect. Perhaps you should read the article.

Answer (score 0):

(Similar to the answer on identity which is closest so far.)

There is also the term: "Acts of Identity," which is essentially which is essentially convergence-type behaviour, discussed by LePlage & Tabouret-Keller, 1985 [here](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=cbQ8AAAAIAAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=LePage%20%26%20Tabouret-Keller,%201985&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CC4Q6AEwAGoVChMI84DpsODwxgIVSL4UCh0WegIJ#v=onepage&q=LePage%20%26%20Tabouret-Keller%2C%201985&f=false).

Answer (score 0):

You know the saying: "Birds of a feather flock together."

So, if you sing 'different' and are self-conscious about it, you might think of yourself as

> "a sing-ular bird of a feather"!

The phrase does not exist… yet, of course!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the *imposed norm hypothesis*?  Here's a quote:

> Previous work suggests that standard dialects assume their prestige over other language varieties not because they are linguistically or aesthetically superior, but because of historical, cultural norms. An empirical investigation lends this view support *etc.*

From http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00335637409383249?journalCode=rqjs20#.VbHFjfkhE8I

Answer (score 0):

You might consider **internalized oppression** (def:  the process by which a member of an oppressed and usually minority group comes to accept and live out the inaccurate myths and stereotypes applied to the group).

One manifestation of this is the belief that one's accent is ugly or otherwise inferior to the "norm," and results in some people taking diction classes for the same reasons that, for example, some African-Americans historically used skin lightening cream.

My own Northern English Mum dedicated herself assiduously to shedding her Geordie accent when she moved to London ... although she would hardly describe herself as oppressed or having internalized her oppression!

Answer (score -2):

A person who is shibboleth conscious?

[A shibboleth](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/shibboleth) is a word from the Hebrew Bible, and it means "torrent of water." This word was used by one tribe to distinguish their tribe who pronounced the word *šibbōlet*, from another tribe who pronounced the same word *sibbōlet* (see Judges 12:4-6).

Comment: @Centaurus  No answer yet to your question about a technical phrase meaning insecure about one's accent?  I saw it on Linguistics, unanswered.  I am curious about this.  It is one of the very few questions asked here that can't be answered by adept Googling.

Comment: @ab2  I've found the term I was looking for [here](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=c55ZBAAAQBAJ&pg=PA54&dq=linguistic+self-hatred&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCIQ6AEwAWoVChMI95Xp8Oe9xwIViX6QCh2D4AXu#v=onepage&q=linguistic%20self-hatred&f=false)

Answer (score -2):

insecure - which is really a word

Comment: +1 for insecure.  It is exactly what the OP described.  You still would have to complement it with `about an accent`

Comment: The question has been re-edited and some more information added.